Create Razorpay Order in my Django DRF project gives 401 Error. "Authentication credentials were not provided."
Im trying to create a view where we create an order through razorpay, but continuously getting 401 error despite the keyId and KeySecret being correct. Even postman and curl gives the same error.  I have tried removing the authentication, adding authentication through postman etc, but the issue persists. The Key works for razorpay's global API correctly, but the error is only in my function.  Any help would be welcome thanks
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic cnpwX3Rlc3RfNGZTSXNRaWdoeTZnU3o6Y1pZT3pvbnRWOFlEM1V1bzFneVlYalVF" -d "{\"amount\": 10000, \"currency\": \"INR\", \"receipt\": \"order_receipt\"}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/create-razorpay-order/
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}



path('create-razorpay-order/', views.create_razorpay_order, name="create_razorpay_order"),

def create_razorpay_order(request):    
 
    razorpay_key = 'KEYID'
    razorpay_secret = 'RAZORPAYKEYSECRET'
    
    # Concatenating the API key and secret with a colon
    key_id_secret = f'{razorpay_key}:{razorpay_secret}'
    
    # Base64 encode the concatenated string
    base64_encoded_key_id_secret = base64.b64encode(key_id_secret.encode()).decode()

    # Endpoint for creating an order on Razorpay's server
    razorpay_order_url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders'
    
    # Amount in paise (e.g., 10000 represents ₹100.00)
    amount = 10000
    
    # Data to be sent in the request body
    data = {
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': 'INR',  # Currency code (e.g., INR for Indian Rupees)
        'receipt': 'order_receipt1',  # Unique identifier for the order (optional)
        
    }
    
    # Headers for the request
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Basic {base64_encoded_key_id_secret}',
    }
    
    # Make a POST request to create the order on Razorpay's server
    response = requests.post(razorpay_order_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # order_id = order_data.get('id')
        return Response(response.json())
    else:
        # If the request fails, return an error response
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Failed to create order'}, status=response.status_code)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #cors header middleware
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   
]


Authorization: Basic ... are you sure that is supposed to be Basic and not Token (default with TokenAuthentication) or something like Bearer? What's your DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES set to?

Default authentication is dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication, so it is Bearer.  I have used @csrf_excempt to avoid this but still issue persists.

I also tried adding Basic authentication after JWT in Default Authentication Classes, now I get a wrong a username/password error.
'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'

Given your JWTCookieAuthentication expects a Bearer token in the authorization header and you know it why are you not sending it? Why are you sending Basic instead?
